# How to move the slider of scale slider with the value of two scale slider with tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I want to make three scale slider in tkinter in Python, where I can move the slider of first two and the third slider moves itself as the sum of the values of first two sliders

I tried with the following code where I try to set the value of first two to the third.

```py
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
#First Scale
w1=Scale(master, from_=0, to=100,orient=HORIZONTAL) 
w1.pack() 
#Second Scale
w2=Scale(master, from_=0, to=200,orient=HORIZONTAL) 
w2.pack() 

#Third Scale where sum has to be shown
w3=Scale(master, from_=0, to=300,orient=HORIZONTAL) 
w3.set(w1.get()+w2.get())
w3.pack() 
mainloop()
```

The expectation is to move the first two sliders and the third slider moves itself to the value which is sum of the values of first two sliders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `IntVar` as variables for your first two `Scale`, then trace the changes and set the third `Scale`.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
#First Scale
w1_var = IntVar()
w1=Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, variable=w1_var, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w1.pack()
#Second Scale
w2_var = IntVar()
w2=Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, variable=w2_var, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w2.pack()   

#Third Scale where sum has to be shown
w3=Scale(master, from_=0, to=300,orient=HORIZONTAL,state="disabled")
w3.pack()

def trace_method(*args):
    w3.config(state="normal")
    w3.set(w1.get() + w2.get())
    w3.config(state="disabled")

w1_var.trace("w", trace_method)
w2_var.trace("w", trace_method)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: One more thing, Can we make the third scale only move when first two scales move. Third scale should not be moved manually.

Comment: Of course - but you will need to make a function to enable/disable it.

Comment: Its done.`from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
w1_var = IntVar()
w2_var = IntVar()
w3_var = IntVar()
w1=Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, variable=w1_var, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w1.pack()
w2=Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, variable=w2_var, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w2.pack()   
#Third Scale where sum has to be shown
w3=Scale(master, from_=0, to=300,variable=w3_var,orient=HORIZONTAL)
w1_var.trace("w",lambda *args:w3.set(w1.get()+w2.get()))
w2_var.trace("w",lambda *args:w3.set(w1.get()+w2.get()))
w3_var.trace("w",lambda *args:w3.set(w1.get()+w2.get()))
w3.pack()
mainloop() `